# Como criar uma faixa extendendo uma Image no c#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um metodo para adicionar uma faixa roxa nas imagens que são processadas na minha aplicação. Estou usando o c# para desenhar na imagem, atualmente eu faço assim:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(originalFilePath))
{
    Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    Rectangle FooterRectangle = new Rectangle(0, image.Height - 50, image.Width, 50); // image.height = 450px   image.width = 450px
    SolidBrush footerBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(189, 5, 59));
    imageGraphics.FillRectangle(footerBrush, FooterRectangle);
}
```

O resultado é esse(Ignorar marca d'agua e o texto, foco na faixa roxa):[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai beleza, o problema é, a faixa esta sobrepondo a imagem, eu preciso que ela incremente o height. Por exemplo, a imagem tem 450px x 450px preciso que fique 450px x 500px ou seja, eu não estarei cortando uma parte da foto. Existe uma forma de ao invés de sobre incrementar no height da foto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve criar uma nova imagem, com tamanho maior, e redesenhar sua imagem por cima:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(originalFilePath))
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap novaImagem = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height + 50); //sendo 50 o a altura da sua 'faixa'

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(novaImagem)) //o Graphics vem da nova imagem
    {
        g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(189, 5, 59)); //"limpo" a nova imagem, e deixo ela toda na cor desejada (isso não é roxo, rsrs)

        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0,0,image.Width,image.Height));
        //Aqui, se quiser, você pode colocar o DrawString e escrever o texto...
    }

    return novaImagem;
}
```

Comment: Eu tinha resolvido basicamente da mesma forma ! Obrigado +1

Comment: Não é roxo? kkkkkkkkk é rosa? hahaha

Comment: não kkkk... ta mais pra vermelho... roxo é a imagem do meu perfil =] vlww